# PHP fopen() function does not create a file

Tags: php

I am trying to create a file in my PHP application using the following code:

```php
$file = @fopen(Data::$FILE_PATH, 'w'); //I also tried with 'x'
if(!$file)
{
    new ErrorReporter('Error 3');
    return;
}
```

It always displays the Error 3 text.

PHP script has chmod 777, I tried to make $FILE_PATH:

- /var/www/data.json
- /var/data.json
- /root/data/data.json
- /var/test/data.json

But none of the following worked, the file is never created.

I tried to make a file manually and I debugged it using the following function:

```php
    private function debug()
    {
        $file = Data::$FILE_PATH;

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', true);
        echo 'phpversion: ', phpversion(), "\n";
        echo 'uname: ', php_uname("s r"), "\n"; // name/release of the operating system
        //echo 'sapi: ', php_sapi(), "\n";

        echo $file, file_exists($file) ? ' exists' : ' does not exist', "\n";
        echo $file, is_readable($file) ? ' is readable' : ' is NOT readable', "\n";
        echo $file, is_writable($file) ? ' is writable' : ' is NOT writable', "\n";

        $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
        if ( !$fp ) {
            echo 'last error: ';
            var_dump(error_get_last());
        }
        else {
            echo "ok.\n";
        }
        die('done');
    }
```

The file:

- existed
- is readable
- **ISN'T WRITABLE**

The error that appears in the debug function is:
`failed to open stream: Permission denied in /path/to/the/file on line 108`

Line 108 content:

`$fp = fopen($file, 'w');`

But as I previously said, chmod of the script is 777 and $FILE_PATH file is 664.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: you are not allowed to write in these directories...  it couldn't be more obvious or could be better explained nobody can "fix" for you, use another directory in which you're allowed to write.

Comment: Even in /var/www/data.json?

Comment: The permissions of the script file are irrelevant. It's the permissions of the folder you're attempting to write to that matters, as well as what "user" the script is running as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, I finally found a solution:

I had to change chmod of the destination folder. I did 777, but you can find more secure chmods.

So as a summary - you need to change permissions of a PHP script and the destination folder.